# Flutter : How to add new item to CupertinoPicker

Tags: flutter, dart

I have list data from JSON API and I would to add new item like "Select item" before the list . How can I do that on CupertinoPicker 
this is my code

```
CupertinoPicker( 
                                children:  data.length != 0
                                  ? new List<Widget>.generate(data.length,
                                  (int index) {
                                return new Center(
                                  child: new Text(
                                    data[index]['city'],
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 22,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              })
                              : <Widget>[Text("---")] ,
                              onSelectedItemChanged: (int index) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _myLocation = data[index]['city'];
                                  getSublocation();
                                  _mySublocation = null;
                                });
                              },
                              itemExtent: 32.0,
                            )
```

and this is image to explain what I want
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCMFK.jpg)

Comment: I need help to complete my project .

Comment: item index not show

Answer (score 0):

you can use a column to wrap the select element of yours like so,

```dart
CupertinoPicker(
      children: <Widget>[
        SelectWidget(),// replace this with the widget you want <-------------------------
        data.length == 0
            ? 
            Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                    return Container(
                      child: Center(
                        child: new Text(
                          data[index]['city'],
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 22,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
            : Text("---")
      ],
      onSelectedItemChanged: (int index) {
        setState(() {
          _myLocation = data[index]['city'];
          getSublocation();
          _mySublocation = null;
        });
      },
      itemExtent: 32.0,
    );
```